# adding elements to an array and call sort method

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am having difficulty trying to load 50 elements from my file to the array and call the bubble sort. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I have already loading the entire list to an array. Just need to pick out 50 first or random element from it and call the bubbleSort method.

```
public class Sorts
{
    public static int bubbleCount = 0;

    public static void bubbleSort(double data[], int count)
    {
        int pass, i; 
        double temp;
        boolean done;
        done = false;
        for (pass = 0; !done; pass++)
        { 
            done = true;
            for (i = 0; i < count - 1 - pass; i++)
            {
                bubbleCount++;
                if (data[i] > data[i+1])
                {
                    temp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[i+1];
                    data[i+1] = temp;
                    done = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main class

```
public class MainSort
{
    static File numData;
    static Scanner s;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        numData = new File("Num.dat");   
        try 
        {
            s = new Scanner(numData);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        double[] array = new double[1];
        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            int i=0;
            array[i]=s.nextDouble();
            //print
            //System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;
        }
        Sorts sorted = new Sorts();
        sorted.bubbleSort(array[50]);

    }
}
```

Comment: What 'difficulty' are you having?

Comment: with the help of the 2 comments below, I fixed the array part. I do get an array index out of bound exception because there are thousands of elements in that list. Also I still can not call my bubbleSort method. It tells me it requires type double[],int but found type double. Reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `int i` outside the loop:

```
      int i=0;

     while(s.hasNext()){
            array[i]=s.nextDouble();
            //print
            //System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this piece of code

```
int i=0;
array[i]=s.nextDouble();
```

You have declared `int i = 0;` var inside while loop. Every time it is getting set to 0.
So in the array also, every time value at index 0 is replaced with the new value.

Declare `int i`outside `while`loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(s.hasNext()) {
  array[i]=s.nextDouble();
  i++;
}
```